# Make Bash autocomplete guess the closest approximation

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a somewhat uncomfortable keyboard on my laptop, resulting in that I sometimes misspell things in Bash and when pressing Tab for an auto-completion nothing happens.

Is it possible to have Bash guess what I meant to type, by for example when wanting to change directory to Documents and then mistyping `cd ocum[TAB]`, given no other folder beginning with "ocum" is present, Bash interprets it as `cd Documents/` since it is the closest possible action to do?

Or is this idea terribly complicated to achieve?

Comment: Guessing is hard for computers; could you come up with some patterns you’d like it to try? For example, substituting a missing initial character.

Comment: I think in most cases this guessing mechanism would be helpful is when actually changing directories. That is when I type sluggish and in a hurry. Following the example above, `cd *ments*` does what I want. But using wildcards every time kind of beats the purpose of doing things fast.

Comment: It's not terribly complicated.  The Z shell, if configured to do so, can do _exactly_ the completion described in the question.

Comment: `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'b:=*'`

Answer (score 4):

On *github* there's an *11K* [`fuzzy_bash_completion`](https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion) script that appears to match some of the spec:

> For example:
>
> ```
> mkdir pizza
> mkdir jazz
> cd zz<TAB>
> # displays `pizza' and `jazz'
> rm -r jazz
> cd zz<TAB>
> # completes the word `pizza'
> ```

Comment: I tested it, and it does the job